# register sms receive intent from activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have a receiver private to my activity class. I want to register my receiver for intent `"android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"`. I am able to do so from manifest file but not from my activity.
Activity code for registering receiver:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");

registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Receiver code :

```
 private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

               //some action

            }
        };
```

Please tell if it is possible to do so, and if yes then how.

Comment: if u find your answer then post it..and accept it so that other user can also get solution if they are having the same kind of problem

Comment: the code which was is in ques is working for me. its the answer only